# How to Find Vertex of Polar Parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the vertex of the parabola $r = 2/(1-\cos(\theta))$?

All of the problems are centered at the pole, but this still does not guide me in the right direction. Perhaps knowing the eccentricity $(c/a)$ will be helpful?

Comment: Clearing denominators yields $r-x=2$. Then add $x$, square, and subtract $x^2$ to get $y^2=4(x+1)$. That implies the vertex is at $(-1,0)$.

Comment: What is the eccentricity of a parabola?

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to think of the parabola in the projective plane.
There, the parabola has a single point at infinity, and finding the direction to that point from the origin will give you the orientation of the axis, $\theta_0$.

If you aren't familiar with the projective plane, look for a value $\theta = \theta_0$ at which $r$ is undefined, such that $r \to \infty$ as $\theta \to \theta_0.$

Either way, you should be able to see that $\theta_0 = 0.$
Note that $1 - \cos(0) = 0.$

Since $2/(1-\cos(\theta)) = 2/(1-\cos(-\theta)),$ the parabola is symmetric about the $x$-axis.

This tells you that the vertex of the parabola is on the $x$-axis. Since it cannot be at $\theta=0,$ is is at $\theta=\pi,$

$$ r = \frac{2}{1 - \cos(\pi)} = \frac{2}{1 - (-1)} = 1. $$

So the vertex is at $(r,\theta) = (1,\pi).$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Find a $\theta$ that minimizes $r$.

Comment: eh...? I don't understand how this would work.

Comment: Think graphically. As $cos\theta$ approaches 1, r goes to infinity, and $r(\theta)$ is strictly positive. So the vertex is going to be the minimum $r$ value, where the parabola is closest to the origin.

Comment: r doesn't go to infinity...it creates a (for lack of a better word) parabola.

Comment: For a parabola, r goes to infinity.

Comment: Oh of course...I'm sorry. I was thinking of an ellipse, etc. So I guess your'e right in this regard (well of course you are). But is there a more general rule that will work for all conic sections

Comment: The vertices of any conic section lie at the ends of its major axis. If you can figure out the major axis, you can find the vertex.

Comment: That information isn't even solicited, so that is difficult as well. The polar portion is a subset of the introductory unit to conic sections. As such, it only asks for the directrix, eccentricity, and some other minor questions.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

- $x=r\cos \theta$
- $y=r\sin \theta$

therefore

$$r = \frac2{1-\cos(\theta)} \iff r-r\cos(\theta)=2 \iff \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x=2\iff x=\frac14(y^2-4)$$

from which we find $V=(-1,0)$.